# how calculate grand total and sub total from this table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables like the following:

**table list_acc:**

```
id_acc   nama_acc          parent_id_acc   level_acc   pattern_volume  id_sat  
-------  ----------------  --------------  ----------  --------------  -----------
      1  activities 1              (NULL)           1          (NULL)            1
      2  sub activities 1               1           2               1            1
      3  sub activities 2               1           2               1            1
      4  sub activities 3               1           2               1            1
      5  item sa 3 (1)                  4           3               1            1
      6  item sa 3 (2)                  4           3               1            1
      7  item sa 3 (3)                  4           3               1            1
      8  sub activities 4               1           2               1            1
      9  activities 2              (NULL)           1          (NULL)            1
     10  sub activities 1               9           2               1            2
     11  sub activities 2               9           2               1            2
     12  sub activities 3               9           2               1            2
     13  sub activities 4               9           2               1            2
     14  sub activities 5               9           2               1            2
```

**table nominal:**

```
id_nominal  id_acc   volume      nominal  id_user  
----------  -------  ------  -----------  ---------
         1        2    2.00  15000000.00          1
         2        3    2.00  30000000.00          1
         3        2    2.00  10000000.00          2
         4       10    1.00   5000000.00          2
         5        5    1.00  20000000.00          1
         6       14   10.00   2000000.00          1
```

then I connect the two tables by loading all the list_acc tables and based on the id_user in the nominal table, with the query

```
SELECT 
    level_acc, list_acc.id_acc, parent_id_acc, name_acc, volume, nominal,
    COALESCE(volume * nominal,0) AS total
FROM list_acc
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM nominal
    WHERE id_user = '1') AS tbl_nominal_user
ON list_acc.`id_acc` = tbl_nominal_user.id_acc
ORDER BY list_acc.id_acc
```

so the results are as follows:

```
level_acc  id_acc  parent_id_acc  name_acc          volume      nominal          total  
---------  ------  -------------  ----------------  ------  -----------  ---------------
    1       1         (NULL)  activities 1      (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
    2       2              1  sub activities 1    2.00  15000000.00    30000000.0000
    2       3              1  sub activities 2    2.00  30000000.00    60000000.0000
    2       4              1  sub activities 3  (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
    3       5              4  item sa 3 (1)       1.00  20000000.00    20000000.0000
    3       6              4  item sa 3 (2)     (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
    3       7              4  item sa 3 (3)     (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
    2       8              1  sub activities 4  (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
    1       9         (NULL)  activities 2      (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
    2      10              9  sub activities 1  (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
    2      11              9  sub activities 2  (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
    2      12              9  sub activities 3  (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
    2      13              9  sub activities 4  (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
    2      14              9  sub activities 5   10.00   2000000.00    20000000.0000
```

then I want to calculate the total from sub activities 3, where the total is obtained from the total item sa 3 or parrent id 4.
then, total activities 1 and 2, where the total is obtained from total sub activities

how to write a query on mysql?

**The expected results are**

```
    level_acc  id_acc  parent_id_acc  name_acc          volume      nominal          total  
    ---------  ------  -------------  ----------------  ------  -----------  ---------------
            1       1         (NULL)  activities 1      (NULL)       (NULL)   110000000.0000
            2       2              1  sub activities 1    2.00  15000000.00    30000000.0000
            2       3              1  sub activities 2    2.00  30000000.00    60000000.0000
            2       4              1  sub activities 3  (NULL)       (NULL)    20000000.0000
            3       5              4  item sa 3 (1)       1.00  20000000.00    20000000.0000
            3       6              4  item sa 3 (2)     (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
            3       7              4  item sa 3 (3)     (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
            2       8              1  sub activities 4  (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
            1       9         (NULL)  activities 2      (NULL)       (NULL)    20000000.0000
            2      10              9  sub activities 1  (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
            2      11              9  sub activities 2  (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
            2      12              9  sub activities 3  (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
            2      13              9  sub activities 4  (NULL)       (NULL)           0.0000
            2      14              9  sub activities 5   10.00   2000000.00    20000000.0000
```

Comment: Can you put your data in text format along will expected result, that would be helpful

Comment: I put the data in the question.

Comment: You seem to want a recursive query. This is only available as of MySQL 8. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive

Comment: mysql that I have is version 5. so is the server. is there a way to query that can be used in mysql 5 either by using a sub query?

Comment: Please give step by step calculations for calculating total for a row. for example: "sub activities 2"

Comment: how to calculate it is to look at the relationship between parent_id_acc and id_acc. for example, to calculate the row id_acc 1, then by adding up the whole parent_id_acc 1. then to calculate the row id_acc 4, then by adding up all parent_id_acc 4. so to calculate the row id_acc 9, then by adding all parent_id_acc 9. hopefully it can be understood